# Web API, API Controller and how to update a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying out the API controller in MVC 4 and have a question about best practice when using put, updating an object.

I'm using RavenDB as data storage and I have created a custom MediaTypeFormatter that has a converter of type JsonDynamicConverter that can serialize and deserialize json to a dynamic object. With that said my API controllers Put method looks like this

```
 public void Put(string id, dynamic model) {}
```

this dynamic object looks sorta like this:

```
pageModel = {
  "id": "pages-2",
  "metadata": {
    "changed": "2012-02-28T17:16:27.323Z"
  },
  "parent": {
    "id": "pages-1",
    "slug": null
  },
  "children": []
}
```

so, so far so good but now I need to update my entity with id pages-2.
The UpdateModel does not exist in the ApiController so my question is what is the best/preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply call RavenDB to load the object with the appropriate ID, make the changes to its contents and persist it again.

No need to worry about any UpdateModel calls.  It doesn't apply here.

Be aware of one potential issue since you are including the id in the model. If I sent a PUT command to http://server/controller/pages-3 with that body what would happen?  You should probably send me a bad request response or something similar depending on how you want your API to work.

Comment: "make the changes to its contents" this is exactly what I mean, in standard MVC I can use UpdateModel to update whatever object I have but what options do I have to merge two objects in .net? Maybe I have the wrong approach to this problem, but I think It's pretty straight forward, I want to save/update whatever object where the only thing I'm certain of is that it implements the same interface or base class, I'm also certain that the object i receive is extended in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to be explicit in your parameters? I would define an UpdateModel and take that as parameter instead of the dynamic. Then it also would be able to model validation.

ASP.NET WebApi includes handling of converting from both JSON and XML as input to your controller methods. I'm guessing your combination of custom mediatypeformatter and use of dynamic would be unneccesary in this case, if there is not something I'm missing.